# Multi-VRF inetrfaces to a single docker

Tags: docker, interface, namespaces, router, cisco-ios

I am facing the same prolem, I wanted this for the sake of associating multiple physical interface son IOS-xr rouuters to a single container. Issue here is the the cisco router with ios xr has got the various vrf . interfaces are associated to global as well as other vrf's. each vrf is associated to differen namespace. When it comes o the container , the container can only see certain physical interfaces that are associated to that namespace which in turn as associated to global vrf or certain vrf. Practically in need a application running on container to send traffic on interfaces asociated with different namespaces or different vrfs. But this does not seems to be available.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by ip netns from host system.

I use simple scripts and i look as working (**But not persistenet** between container powercycle)

1. Add networkNamespace of my container to host system (**dhcp** is name of my container)

```
pid="$(docker inspect -f '{{.State.Pid}}' "dhcp")"
mkdir -p /var/run/netns
ln -sf /proc/$pid/ns/net "/var/run/netns/dhcp"
```

2. create script.sh which add vrf and assign interface to vrf

```
ip link add dev vrf_m_0 type vrf table 100
ip link set dev vrf_m_0 up
ip link set dev eth0 master vrf_m_0

ip link add dev vrf_m_1 type vrf table 101
ip link set dev vrf_m_1 up
ip link set dev eth1 master vrf_m_1
```

3. Run script under networkNamespece

```
ip netns exec dhcp bash script.sh
```

**Edit**
if you want persistent solution
you mast add linux capability for net admin operation  `--cap-add NET_ADMIN`  and change entrypoint script to add vrf on every start